# AS3 clone MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

The below is my code for trying to clone the MovieClip and it doesn't work.
We should see two cirles if the codes is working correctly.

```
/*The original MovieClip*/
var circle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0xAA0022);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);
circle.x=10
addChild(circle);

/*CLONE the MovieClip - IT DOES'T WORK FROM HERE DOWN*/
var cloneCirle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    cloneCirle=circle
    cloneCirle.x=60 
    addChild(cloneCirle);
```

Answer (score 8):

When you do `cloneCircle=circle`, it's not copying or cloning anything. It's just saying that the variable `cloneCircle` is another name for your original `circle` MovieClip. What you need to do is use the [Graphics.copyFrom()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#copyFrom()) method.

Try it:

```
var cloneCircle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
cloneCircle.graphics.copyFrom(circle.graphics);
cloneCircle.x = 60;
addChild(cloneCircle);
```

Comment: umm I am getting the "Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 18 1120: Access of undefined property cloneCircle."

Comment: I got it var cloneCirle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
cloneCirle.graphics.copyFrom(circle.graphics);
cloneCirle.x=60;
addChild(cloneCirle);

Answer (score 4):

This is for creating a duplicate of a stage object that exists in the FLA library at compile time

The object must have a 'Export for Actionscript ticked in it's properties panel and a valid class name in the 'Class' box

If the symbol only has a single frame just add another so it registers as `MovieClip()` rather than `Sprite()`

```
private function cloneObject(source:DisplayObject):void
{
    var objectClass:Class = Object(source).constructor;
    var instance:MovieClip = new objectClass() as MovieClip;
    instance.transform = source.transform;
    instance.filters = source.filters;
    instance.cacheAsBitmap = source.cacheAsBitmap;
    instance.opaqueBackground = source.opaqueBackground;
    source.parent.addChild(instance);
    instance.x += 20; // just to show the duplicate exists!
}
```

http://snipplr.com/view/44734/

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from [here](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/flash-as3-duplicate-movieclip-objects-function/):

```
function copyClip( clip:MovieClip )
{
    var sourceClass:Class = Object(clip).constructor;
    var duplicate:MovieClip = new sourceClass();
    return duplicate;
}
```