# Create a copy of existing movieclip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a library movieclip: Cards. On Cards every frame is a card (vector) (e.g. frame 1: club Ace, frame 2: club 2, etc).
I created a new instance of Cards and converted every frame to bitmap (so now club Ace on frame 1 is a bitmap), and now I want every card (that I will add) on the stage to be a copy of converted object.

```
var cachedCard:Cards = new Cards();
// [...] for every frame convert that frame to bitmap, remove original children and add bitmap instead
var newCard:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
newCard = cachedCard; 
// I understand that this is not working, 
// a similar example would be with arrays, array1 = array2, 
// array1 is just another name for array2, 
// but you can use array1.concat(array2) and now array1 is separated from array2 
// Can I do something similar with movieclips ?!
```

I already tried this solutions: 
[AS3 clone MovieClip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999061/as3-clone-movieclip)

I tried this:

```
function copyClip( clip:MovieClip )
{
    var sourceClass:Class = Object(clip).constructor;
    var duplicate:MovieClip = new sourceClass();
    return duplicate;
}

var card:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
card = copyClip(cachedCard);
```

but it creates a new instance of original Cards, not the one with bitmaps in it.

How do I use the modified Cards movieclip (the one with bitmaps) to assign it to every new card I add to stage?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use the modified Cards movieclip (the one with bitmaps) to assign it to every new card I add to stage?

It looks like you have a linked class called "Cards". You can simply just instantiate that class to generate the movieclip again. Ie.

```
var newCard:Card = new Card();
```

Previously you were setting a new MovieClip to the already instantiated card class here:

```
newCard = cachedCard;
```

However, if your Card movieclip has a bitmap on each frame that shows the card information, you can also create bitmaps of each card like so:

```
public function createCard( frame:int ):Bitmap
{
    cachedCard.gotoAndStop( frame );

    var cardBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( cachedCard.width, cachedCard.height, true, 0 );
    cardBitmapData.draw( cachedCard );

    return new Bitmap( cardBitmapData );
}
```

Comment: Yes, seems right, thank you, but the problem is that I need to create a new bitmap every time the card flips. What I wanted to do is to create the bitmaps for cards once (52 cards + back) and then reuse this bitmaps, I don't want to draw again and again for every card flip.

Comment: Then you will want to create an array of bitmap data instances. Then you can just swap the bitmap data for each bitmap. Eg, using the above implementation, and an array of BitmapData, `someCardBitmap.bitmapData = arrayOfBitmapData[ index ]`